# Generating hashcodes for specific filetypes only with Powershell

Tags: powershell, out-gridview, filehash

I'm a complete beginner to Powershell and scripting, and have been successfully been using Out-GridView to display some properties of the files I have in my directories using the following:

`dir D:\Folder1\$type -Recurse | Select Fullname,Directory,LastWriteTime | out-gridview`

where I specifiy the file extension with `$type = "*.pdf"` for instance.

I would also like to start comparing files using hashcodes so I have tried this command:

`ls | Get-Filehash`

However, I would like to have the hashcodes in the output window as a seperate column with out-gridview. Is this possible? I've tried

`dir D:\Folder1\$type -Recurse | Select Fullname,Directory,LastWriteTime,Filehash | out-gridview`

and

`dir D:\Folder1\$type -Recurse | Select Fullname,Directory,LastWriteTime | Get-Filehash | out-gridview`

Of course neither of these work.

Does anyone have a way of generating hashcodes for a specific file extension only?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a calculated property with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Folder1\$type'-Recurse |
    Select-Object FullName,Directory,LastWriteTime, @{Label='FileHash'; Expression={(Get-Filehash -Path $_.FullName).Hash}} |
        Out-GridView
```

You should see a new column in the grid view called 'Filehash' that contains the SHA256 hash of the file.  You can chage the algorithm (to, say, MD5) using the `-Algorithm` parameter of `Get-FileHash`.

If you're wondering what this is doing, the important parts are:

`@{...}`
signifies a hashtable.  e.g. a set of key-value pairs

`label`
is the key that defines what your property (column name) will be in the grid view

`expression` defines the code snippet (`{...}`) that calculates the value of this property

`$_`
signifies that we are working with the 'current' object (file in this case) passing along the pipeline